# most read pages - drupal

Tags: drupal

i would like to have a block on my drupal site(latest version) that displays most read pages on the website

is there any module/code available to achieve this?

-Vivek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the '[statistics](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/statistics)' module that comes with a default Drupal installation. It tracks node views and offers some rudimentary overview pages itself, but its data can be accessed and used from View module views.

Comment: While this is a quick and easy way to solve the problem, you have to be aware that this causes a write query on every node view, which can cause performance problems on a site with many visitors.

Answer (score 0):

As Drupal does not have "pages" as atomic units but nodes, you probably want to have a list of the most viewed nodes, and then perhaps only of a certain type.

1. Count the views per node (or content-type), look for a module that does this
2. Create a view with the Views module that creates the list of most-viewed nodes
3. Let Views output a block with that list
4. Display the block where you want it

Comment: which is exactly the path you should follow using the statistics core module mentioned above.